# When is $\frac{k^2-71}{7k+55}$ (where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$) a positive integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

When is $\dfrac{k^2-71}{7k+55}$ (where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$) a positive integer?

I can't seem to find a angle of attack for this kind of question whether I'm restricting myself to high school mathematics or not.

Any hint or solution is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number $$7\cdot\frac{k^2-71}{7k+55}=\frac{7k^2-497}{7k+55}=k-\frac{55k+497}{7k+55}=k-8+\frac{k-57}{7k+55}$$
must also be an integer and so must
$$ 7\cdot \frac{k-57}{7k+55} = 1-\frac{454}{7k+55}.$$
Hence $7k+55$ must be one of the divisors of $454$, that is $\pm1,\pm2, \pm227,\pm454$. Check if these result in an integer for $k$ and an then a positive integer for $\frac{k^2-71}{7k+55}$. (You should find two values of $k$, both of which produce the same positive integer).

Answer (score 2):

If $d|(7k+55)$ and $d|(k^2-71)\implies d|\{k(7k+55)-7(k^2-71)\}\implies d|(55k+497)$

Now, $d|(7k+55)$ and $ d|(55k+497)\implies d|\{55(7k+55)-7(55k+497)\}\implies d|454$

Now, the divisors of $454$ are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm227,\pm454$

Comment: (+1). And another divisor is $\pm 454$.

Comment: @Inceptio, thanks for your observation.Rectified.